# Export multiple snowflake query result into separate CSV files

Tags: python, csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have stored multiple snowflake queries in an excel file and i'm trying to write a python program to execute those queries and export the result set into different CSV files in my local path.
When I execute the program, it reads all the queries but exports only one query result into a CSV file.

```
from EXCEL_CONNECTION import * ---python program for snowflake connection
from SNOWFLAKE_CONNECTION import *--- python program for excel connection
import pandas

  cur = ctx.cursor()
  try:

     for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, min_col=2):
        for cell in row:
          cur.execute(cell.value)
          #one_row = cur.fetchall()
          df = cur.fetch_pandas_all()
         df.to_csv(r"excel_output_path\table.csv")
 finally:
     cur.close()
  cur.close()
```

I couldn't figure out the mistake I'm doing and would really need some help here to make this work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are writing all results to the same files, so they are overwriting each other

```
df.to_csv(r"excel_output_path\table.csv")
```

```
     count = 0
     for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, min_col=2):
        for cell in row:
          cur.execute(cell.value)
          #one_row = cur.fetchall()
          df = cur.fetch_pandas_all()
         df.to_csv(r"excel_output_path\table" + str(count) + r".csv")
         count += 1
```

Comment: This worked perfect. Is there a way we can add column value itself as CSV file name instead of count. 
like  having two columns(Column A) in an excel which has value like 'Count' in first row and 'Attribute' in second row and so on and another column(Column B) which has SQL's s when saving the result from the Query set and saving the file with the file name as Column A. I tried with a little modification in the script but instead of appending the Column A value its appending the query itself as file name which is throwing error.

Comment: I don't think you can do it data driven, you ether in python or snowflake scripting (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/) find all the distinct values, then loop export those, with a WHERE cluase that matches the COOP command filename.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for your guidance.